# convert relaxng file that include reference to another relax ng file to xsd

Tags: xml, xsd, relaxng, relaxng-compact

I am going to convert relaxng compact file to xsd. 
So the command to user here would be:

```
java -jar tang.jar test.rng newtest.xsd
```

My question here is as follow:
I have several rnc file in which some of them have the reference to another rnc file. For example I have test1.rnc as follow:

```
start= test
test = 
  element test {
  (element ref {xsd:anyURL}?,
   element links {
     element link {
         attribute handle {text},
         attribute id {text}
      }*
   }?,
   element name { text }?,
   external "util/phone.rnc"?
}
```

and in the util folder I have phone.rnc which is like this:

```
start = phone
phone = 
   element phone {
     element number {
       element phonenumber {text }' 
       element type { text }?
    },
  }
```

So my question is that how can I convert them to xsd in a correct way?
I tried trang but got `test.rnc:29:6: error: sorry, externalRef is not yet supported`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First run jing on the schema with the `-s` option to generate a “simplified“ version:

```
java -jar jing.jar -s -c test.rnc > test-simplified.rnc
```

Then give that simplified schema as input to trang:

```
java -jar trang.jar test-simplified.rnc newtest.xsd
```

If the version of jing you have doesn’t provide the `-s` option, then you need to either find and install a new version, or else just build a new version from the sources:

```
git clone https://github.com/relaxng/jing-trang.git
cd jing-trang
./ant
java -jar build/jing.jar
```

The last command should emit something like this:

```
Jing version 20151127
usage: java com.thaiopensource.relaxng.util.Driver [-i] [-c] [-s] [-t] [-C catalogFile] [-e encoding] RNGFile XMLFile...
RELAX NG is a schema language for XML
See http://relaxng.org/ for more information.
```